# Tool for XML XSD schema validation

Tags: validation, xsd

Does anybody know of a command line tool for validating XML with XSD schema?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

xmllint from the [Libxml project](http://xmlsoft.org/)

```
xmllint --schema schema.xsd doc.xml
```

Comment: Any way to avoid having to specify the schema? (since it's already specified in the XML itself as `xsi:schemaLocation`...)

Comment: -valid option to validate schema with the specified xml inside, but I think --schema is also needed.

Answer (score 3):

On http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema under "Tools" you should find the one which fits your need. I would think it’s oNVDL.

Answer (score 0):

**mono-xmltool**, see

- https://github.com/mono/linux-packaging-mono/blob/master/man/mono-xmltool.1
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/mono-xmltool.1.html

for example

```
mono-xmltool --validate-xsd schema.xsd doc.xml
```

Answer (score -8):

in C#,

```
// xsv.cs
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Validate an XML document against a schema.
//
// last saved:
// Time-stamp: <2010-May-06 00:28:44>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Copyright (c) 2010 by Dino Chiesa
// All rights reserved!
//
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Cheeso.Tools.XmlSchemaValidator")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Xml Schema Validator")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Dino Chiesa")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Tools")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © Dino Chiesa 2010")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.1.1")]

namespace Cheeso.Tools
{
    public class XmlSchemaValidator
    {
        String _xsdfile;
        String _xmlfile;

        private void Validate()
        {
            List<String> validationErrors = new List<String>();
            List<String> validationWarnings = new List<String> ();

            Action<object, ValidationEventArgs> handler = (obj, args) => {
                if (args.Severity==XmlSeverityType.Warning)
                    validationWarnings.Add(args.Message);
                else
                    validationErrors.Add(args.Message);
            };

            XmlTextReader tr = new XmlTextReader(_xmlfile);

            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings
                {
                    ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
                };

            settings.Schemas.Add(null, _xsdfile);
            settings.ValidationEventHandler +=
                new ValidationEventHandler(handler);

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(tr, settings);


            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.Load(reader);

            // Check results
            if (validationErrors.Count > 0)
            {
                validationErrors.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                Console.WriteLine("The XML document is not valid, according to that Schema.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (validationWarnings.Count > 0)
                {
                    validationWarnings.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("The XML document is valid, according to that Schema.");
            }
        }


        public static void Usage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nxsv: validate an XML document against an XML Schema.\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Usage:\n  xsv <xmldoc> <xmlschema>");
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }


        public XmlSchemaValidator (string[] args)
        {
            for (int i=0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                if (args[i] == "-h" ||
                    args[i] == "--help" ||
                    args[i] == "-?")
                {
                    Usage();
                }


                if (_xmlfile == null)
                    _xmlfile = args[i];
                else if (_xsdfile == null)
                    _xsdfile = args[i];
                else
                    Usage();
            }

            // default values
            if (_xmlfile == null ||  _xsdfile == null)
                Usage();
        }


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                new XmlSchemaValidator(args)
                    .Validate();
            }
            catch (System.Exception exc1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", exc1.ToString());
                Usage();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Question was for command line tool

Comment: You posted this example but put "All Rights Reserved" at the top??