# How to validate metadata.xml against .dtd in gentoo?

Tags: metadata, dtd, gentoo

I am trying to validate [metadata.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gentoo/dotnet/master/dev-dotnet/referenceassemblies-pcl/metadata.xml) against [www.gentoo.org/dtd/metadata.dtd](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/data/dtd.git/plain/metadata.dtd) with [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) from [=dev-libs/libxml2-2.9.3](http://gpo.zugaina.org/dev-libs/libxml2) ebuild.

I tried the commands (some from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573399/tool-for-xml-xsd-schema-validation)):

```
$ xmllint --noout --valid  metadata.xml
error : Unknown IO error
metadata.xml:2: warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.gentoo.org/dtd/metadata.dtd"
```

the same for `xmllint  metadata.xml --dtdvalid metadata.dtd`
and `xmllint --loaddtd http://www.gentoo.org/dtd/metadata.dtd`

```
$ xmllint --valid  metadata.xml --schema metadata.dtd
metadata.dtd:1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name
```

I need xmllint and not [mono-xmltool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465335/how-to-validate-an-xml-document) ([from C#/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658325)) because xmllint is used in `repoman -d` command. And repoman is used for gentoo overlay validation in travis-ci

How to validate xml with xmllint properly?

UPD:
site returns "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" and that is why load fails

part of strace:

```
recvfrom(3, "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n"..., 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 446
recvfrom(3, "", 4096, 0, NULL, NULL)    = 0
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "error : ", 8error : )                 = 8
write(2, "Unknown IO error\n", 17Unknown IO error
```

probably libxml2 doesn't do https

```
USE="icu ipv6 python readline -debug -examples -lzma -static-libs {-test}"
```

libxml2 uses nanoHTTP, [nanoHTTP can work with HTTPS](http://csoap.sourceforge.net/docs/snapshot/libsoap-doc-api/html/nanohttp_page.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption was right, the problem is HTTPS. To work around this and to save some BW and time, `repoman` validates against a local file, which it prefetches if not found. The default location is either `REPO_ROOT/metadata/dtd/metadata.dtd` or `DISTDIR/metadata.dtd`. To get the exact arguments `repoman` uses for `xmllint` you have to have a look at its source code - [here](https://github.com/gentoo/portage/blob/8504698e23dd3c51451ce9137fc74f66366a542d/pym/repoman/_xml.py#L97). As you can see, it's

```
xmllint --nonet --noout --dtdvalid <metadata.dtd> metadata.xml
```

This command still outputs:

```
metadata.xml:2: warning: failed to load external entity "https://www.gentoo.org/dtd/metadata.dtd"
<!DOCTYPE pkgmetadata SYSTEM "https://www.gentoo.org/dtd/metadata.dtd">
```

or in case of HTTP:

```
I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://www.gentoo.org/dtd/metadata.dtd
metadata.xml:2: warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.gentoo.org/dtd/metadata.dtd"
<!DOCTYPE pkgmetadata SYSTEM "http://www.gentoo.org/dtd/metadata.dtd">
```

But only as a warning, so the command exits with 0.